# What does somebody mean when he enthusiastically exclaims "Strike!"

Tags: idioms

I think somebody might be expressing the feeling of winning something, possibly making a winning pose with his fist and flexing the biceps. But where does this expression come from and what does it mean exactly in this context?

Comment: If it's a pithy comment that is unanswered, it is a little like a baseball pitcher throwing a pitch that enters the strike zone without the batter attempting to swing. Umpires around the world will add a syllable to this (normally) one-syllable word, and exclaim "Stee-rike!"

Comment: I would tend to associate it with a "strike" in US bowling -- knocking down all ten pins with one roll of the ball.